# Detecting a Specific Watermark in a Photo with Python (without SciPy)

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, image-comparison

I have a large number of images (hundreds of thousands) and, for each one, I need to say whether or not it has a watermark in the top right corner. The watermark is always the same and is in the same position. It takes the form of a ribbon with a symbol and some text. I'm looking for simple and fast way to do this that, ideally, doesn't use SciPy (as it's not available on the server I'm using -- but it can use NumPy)

So far, I've tried using PIL and the crop function to isolate the area of the image where the watermark should be and then compared the histograms with a RMS function (see http://snipplr.com/view/757/compare-two-pil-images-in-python/). That doesn't work very well as there are lots of errors in both directions.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you creating the watermarks also ? could you not just add some raw binary data after the stop bit in the file?

Comment: Is the watermark opaque? If so, then I guess the operation of adding the watermark to the image is more-or-less idempotent. Maybe you could test by somehow comparing the stored image with a version that has had the watermark added on top.

Comment: @Joran-Beasley - I'm not creating the watermarks, no

Comment: @Hammerite - The watermark is partially transparent. I can get access to a version of the file without the watermark but it's in a different resolution, which I presume would complicate things

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another possibility is to use machine learning. My background is natural language processing (not computer vision), but I tried creating a training and testing set using the description of your problem and it seems to work (100% accuracy on unseen data).

#### Training set

The training set consisted of the same images with the watermark (positive example), and without the watermark (negative example).

#### Testing set

The testing set consists of images that were not in the training set.

#### Example data

If interested, you can try it with the [example training and testing images](http://bwbaugh.com/stack-overflow/16222178_watermark.tar).

#### Code:

Full version available [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/bwbaugh/5463151). Excerpt below:

```
import glob

from classify import MultinomialNB
from PIL import Image


TRAINING_POSITIVE = 'training-positive/*.jpg'
TRAINING_NEGATIVE = 'training-negative/*.jpg'
TEST_POSITIVE = 'test-positive/*.jpg'
TEST_NEGATIVE = 'test-negative/*.jpg'

# How many pixels to grab from the top-right of image.
CROP_WIDTH, CROP_HEIGHT = 100, 100
RESIZED = (16, 16)


def get_image_data(infile):
    image = Image.open(infile)
    width, height = image.size
    # left upper right lower
    box = width - CROP_WIDTH, 0, width, CROP_HEIGHT
    region = image.crop(box)
    resized = region.resize(RESIZED)
    data = resized.getdata()
    # Convert RGB to simple averaged value.
    data = [sum(pixel) / 3 for pixel in data]
    # Combine location and value.
    values = []
    for location, value in enumerate(data):
        values.extend([location] * value)
    return values


def main():
    watermark = MultinomialNB()
    # Training
    count = 0
    for infile in glob.glob(TRAINING_POSITIVE):
        data = get_image_data(infile)
        watermark.train((data, 'positive'))
        count += 1
        print 'Training', count
    for infile in glob.glob(TRAINING_NEGATIVE):
        data = get_image_data(infile)
        watermark.train((data, 'negative'))
        count += 1
        print 'Training', count
    # Testing
    correct, total = 0, 0
    for infile in glob.glob(TEST_POSITIVE):
        data = get_image_data(infile)
        prediction = watermark.classify(data)
        if prediction.label == 'positive':
            correct += 1
        total += 1
        print 'Testing ({0} / {1})'.format(correct, total)
    for infile in glob.glob(TEST_NEGATIVE):
        data = get_image_data(infile)
        prediction = watermark.classify(data)
        if prediction.label == 'negative':
            correct += 1
        total += 1
        print 'Testing ({0} / {1})'.format(correct, total)
    print 'Got', correct, 'out of', total, 'correct'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Example output

```
Training 1
Training 2
Training 3
Training 4
Training 5
Training 6
Training 7
Training 8
Training 9
Training 10
Training 11
Training 12
Training 13
Training 14
Testing (1 / 1)
Testing (2 / 2)
Testing (3 / 3)
Testing (4 / 4)
Testing (5 / 5)
Testing (6 / 6)
Testing (7 / 7)
Testing (8 / 8)
Testing (9 / 9)
Testing (10 / 10)
Got 10 out of 10 correct
[Finished in 3.5s]
```

Comment: Wow - fantastic answer. Thank you. I just tested it on my problem and it worked with 100% accuracy (just changed the crop region size).

Comment: How does it find the "watermark" to be found? Is it provided as input or it learns from training set like in "watermark =  MultinomialNB()" variable above. Please confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Is the position of the watermark exact? How is the watermark being applied to the background image?

I'll assume the watermark is a partial add or multiply function. The watermarked image is probably calculated as such:

```
resultPixel = imagePixel + (watermarkPixel*mixinValue)
```

mixinValue would be 0.0-1.0, you could therefore complete the mix by reapplying the watermark with a multiplier of (1-mixinValue). This should result in pixels that match the watermark. Just test to color of the result image against the original watermark.

```
testPixel = resultPixel + (watermarkPixel*(1-mixinValue))
assert testPixel == watermarkPixel
```

Of course compression of the watermarked image will probably cause some variance in your testPixel.

Comment: This sounds good but I didn't create the images so don't have a "clean" copy of the watermark

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the [Specialized Image Recognition](http://restb.ai) API of restb.ai to automate the watermark detection process.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.restb.ai/segmentation"

querystring = {"client_key":"your-free-key-here","model_id":"re_logo","image_url":"http://demo.restb.ai/img/gallery/realestate/logos-watermarks/re_logo-1.jpg"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

[Screenshot of Logo & Watermark detection demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A05ch.png)